# Saving List<String> in flutter using Drift database

Tags: flutter, typeconverter, drift

I need to store a list of strings inside drift database , i have actually set up a typeconverter to do that but i'm not sure exactly how to pass , i would appreciate anyone help , Thank you in advance.

- This is database table  ( class called movies.drift )

```
 
CREATE TABLE movie (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    language TEXT,
    voteAverage TEXT,
    overView TEXT,
    releaseDate TEXT,
    movieImageUrl TEXT,
);
```

- This is my drift helper class

```
 @DriftDatabase(include : {'movies.drift'})
class MovieDatabase extends _$MovieDatabase {
  MovieDatabase() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  Future<List<MovieData>> getMovies() async {
    return await select(movie).get();
  }
  Future<int> saveMovie(MovieCompanion companion) async {
    return await into(movie).insert(companion);
  }
  // Future<int> deleteMovie(int id) async {
  //   return (delete(movie)..where(movie.id.equals(id))).go();
  // }
  Future<int> deleteAllMovies() async {
    return await delete(movie).go();
  }
  Future<int> updateMovie(MovieCompanion companion) async {
    return await update(movie).write(MovieCompanion(
        title: Value(companion.title.toString())
    ));
  }
}

LazyDatabase _openConnection(){
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'movies.db'));
    return NativeDatabase(file);
  });
}
```

- This is my type converter

```
class MovieTypeConverter extends TypeConverter<List<String>,String> {
  const MovieTypeConverter();

  @override
  List<String>? mapToDart(String? fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) return null;
    final data = json.decode(fromDb);
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String? mapToSql(List<String>? value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    return json.encode(value);
  }
  
}
```

PS : I want to basically add List to my table and use typeconverter to save it into database and then retreive it .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs on how to use them:
https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/type_converters/

Example:

> Type converters can also be used inside drift files. Assuming that the
> Preferences and PreferenceConverter are contained in preferences.dart,
> that file can imported into drift for the type converter to be
> available.

```
import 'preferences.dart';

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT,
  preferences TEXT MAPPED BY `const PreferenceConverter()`
);
```

EDIT:

Your `TypeConverter` should have a `fromSql` and `toSql` method.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:drift/drift.dart';

class MovieTypeConverter extends TypeConverter<List<String>?,String?> {
  const MovieTypeConverter();

  @override
  List<String>? fromSql(String? fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) return null;
    return json.decode(fromDb);
  }

  @override
  String? toSql(List<String>? value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    return json.encode(value);
  }
}
```

Your drift file:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    language TEXT,
    voteAverage TEXT,
    overView TEXT,
    releaseDate TEXT,
    movieImageUrl TEXT,
    movieTypes TEXT MAPPED BY `const MovieTypeConverter()`
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i have actually implemented the code as shown on docs , but it sounds like it returns an object class , in my case i want to save List<String>

Comment: @Taki I've updated my answer on how TypeConverters work. Hope it helps